# Properties of the distance function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \Bbb R^n$ be an arbitary nonempty set, and let $0<p<\infty$ be fixed. Let $d(x,A)$ be the distance function.

$$d(x,A) = \inf \{d(x,y)\mid y\in A\}, \qquad E = \{x\in \Bbb R^n \mid d(x,A)=\rho\}$$

1. Prove that $E$ is closed.
2. If $x\in E$, there exists an $x_0\in A^-$ s.t. $|x-x_0|=p$. Also prove that $B(x_0,\rho) \cap E = \phi$.
3. Prove that 
   $$\limsup_{r\to0} \frac{\lambda(E\cap B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))} \leq 1/2.$$
4. Prove that $\lambda (E) = 0$.

I have done the first two parts of this problem, but somehow I am unable to see how to prove the last two parts which deal with measure. 
The problem in part 3. looks as if could be done with using the properties of points of density, but I am not so sure.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier typo . I hope that it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

For part 3, note that $B(x,r)\cap E$ excludes $B(x_0,\rho)$, by part 2. And $x$ sits right on the boundary of the latter ball, also by part 2. As $r$ shrinks, the excluded part will be close (relatively speaking) to one half of $B(x,r)$.

For part 4, use part 3 to show that the outer measure of $E$ is at most one half the outer measure of $E$.